# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Layout while running integration test using ESIntegTestCase

Tags: java, elasticsearch, pom.xml, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to set up integration testing for ElasticSearch in Java.

I extended `ESIntegTestCase` and tried running a dummy empty test.
I get this exception as a result of the test:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/Layout
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive(Class.java:3307)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3293)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2106)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:60)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:55)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.setTestsToRun(JUnit4Provider.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 18 more
```

This happens only when I run any test or try to build module while the testing class extends any class from Elasticsearch Testing Framework in this case `ESIntegTestCase`.
If the testing class doesn't extend anything - tests run just fine.

Here's my POM:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>                    
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>            
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>myModule0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>myModule1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
<!--  tried different versions, nothing seem to resolve this-->
            <version>7.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

It also a child of a module, which following exclusions for spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.5.RELEASE:

```
          <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Elasticsearch (`org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch`) depends on Log4J 2 API and Elasticsearch Testing framework (`org.elasticsearch.test:framework`) depends on Elasticsearch. Importing Log4J 2 Core (implementation) in your test classpath should fix the problem:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.1</version><!-- Elasticsearch v7.6.2 -->
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v7.6.2/buildSrc/version.properties#L19

You can find this relationship by inspecting your Maven project dependencies:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no possibility to test this during quarantine but once I do that and if this is the culprit, I'll get back to this thread.

Comment: @improbable no problem. By the way, I encountered the same issue in my project when learning Elasticsearch. https://github.com/mincong-h/learning-elasticsearch Maybe the code can give you more idea about how the dependencies are organized.

Comment: I just tested this, this resolves log4j problem but brings `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext cannot be cast to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext`

Comment: @improbable, it sounds like a compatibility issue between Log4J and SLF4J. I assume that you are still using 6.4.1 as you mentioned in the question: in this version, Elasticsearch uses Log4J 2.11.1 and SLF4J 1.6.2 ([source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v6.4.1/buildSrc/version.properties#L10-L11)). Are you using these versions in your project?

Comment: No, SLF4J 1.7.25  and log4j-api v. 2.10 are used by Spring.